# standalone problem

Tags: equations, standalone, png

I need to get some equations in `.png`.

Looking for the solution on the web I found that the `standalone` documentclass should do the job using the `convert` option. My code is the following:

```
\documentclass[convert={density=3000,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle
\sum_a^b trial
$
\end{document}
```

Why when I compile it using `pdflatex -shell-escape trial.tex` I got the equation only in `.pdf`? (image magick is already installed)

The same problem appears if I use the sole `convert` option without any sub-option.

Comment: Your code is not the problem, running it I get a .png file. Do you get any error messages?

Comment: In the konsole I find:
"Class standalone Warning: Conversion failed! Please ensure that shell escape
(standalone)              is enabled (e.g. use '-shell-escape')."

But I already used the -shell-escape options

Comment: What `konsole` are you referring to? Is it a bash shell?

Comment: I think that the problem is, that -shell-escape is not enabled. Apparently it is not enough to give the option -shell-escape to pdflatex. What distribution of LaTeX are you using?

Comment: Try `--shell-escape`

Comment: I solved by uninstalling the standalone package and reinstalling it again. I don't know why it now works, but it does. Therefore, as @samcarter noted, the code was right. Thank you all for your time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an installation error and solved by uninstalling the package and reinstalling it again.
